# I want to change the background color of a table row with a button on css

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, the table is auto-incrementing by the user, and I want to use a button to circle 5 colors. I know that the new way to change the color is with the background color.
Oh, and the table is managed by an id.

```
<table class="table table-striped" border="2" >
<thead>
<tr>

<th>id</th>

<th>Cliente</th>

<th>Fecha</th>

<th>Telefono</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<%

while(rs.next())

{

%>


<tr>

<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>

<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>

<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>

<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
</tr>
<%

}

%>
</table>
```

the code on the CSS that I have is this one

```
body {
  font-family: arial;
background-image:url('Imagen3.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
table {
background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the cells
you can add after you css table{}

```
    table td{
       background-color:yellow;
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to implement it on a button so it cicles the row colors?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<tr>...</tr>` table row tag on CSS. If you want to colour a specific row then use id or class with in the  tag then use that id or class in CSS file.
**HTML file:-**

```
<tr id="row1">

<th>id</th>

<th>Cliente</th>

<th>Fecha</th>

<th>Telefono</th>

</tr>
</thead>
```

**CSS file:-**

```
#row1 {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to implement it on a button so it cicles the row colors?

Comment: yes use <td>...</td> table data tag as same